# Assign lines in a text to individual variables (sh or bash, arrays not supported)

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I use the dialog command to prompt the user for input. The result is a text with on each line a value corresponding to the fields.

I want to assign each line back to the variable corresponding to the field. This way I can easily construct control flow and an .ini type of file.

So if I have a form with 3 fields A, B and C, the text in $RESULTS would be: "aaa\nbbb\nccc\n". And I want:

```
$varA to be 'aaa'
$varB to be 'bbb'
$varC to be 'ccc'
```

The alternative seems to be the paste command, but as I need to verify some values before continuing, this would only be a partial solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use `read`.

```
{
    read a
    read b
    read c
} <<< "$RESULTS"
```

or use the more standard here document instead of a here string.

```
{
    read a
    read b
    read c
} <<EOF
$RESULTS
EOF
```

Comment: This is the simplest, but will this hang if a line is missing?

Comment: To answer my own comment after testing: no.

Comment: To comment on your comment :) the here string and here document each constitute a complete virtual file, so any extra reads would exit with non-zero status (end of file) rather than block waiting for more input.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
a=$(echo -e $RESULTS | awk 'NR==1')
b=$(echo -e $RESULTS | awk 'NR==2')
c=$(echo -e $RESULTS | awk 'NR==3')

echo $a,$b,$c
aaa,bbb,ccc
```

Comment: Yes. Good random access method. awk is universally available? sh or bash only?

Comment: If you can't be sure of having `awk`, go with @chepner's eloquent solution.